# Why is my editorconfig not throwing a naming error?

Tags: editorconfig, dotnet-format

Applying a `dotnet_naming_rule` is not triggering a warning via `dotnet format`.

```
# Remove the line below if you want to inherit .editorconfig settings from higher directories
root = true

#### Naming rules ####
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/naming-rules
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE1006.severity = error

# Types should be PascalCase
dotnet_naming_rule.types_should_be_pascal_case.severity = error
dotnet_naming_rule.types_should_be_pascal_case.symbols = type_symbols
dotnet_naming_rule.types_should_be_pascal_case.style = pascal_case

dotnet_naming_symbols.type_symbols.applicable_kinds = class
dotnet_naming_symbols.type_symbols.applicable_accessibilities = *

dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.capitalization = pascal_case
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EditorConfig
{
    public interface barFoo
    {

    }

    class Footype_Cymbolsar : barFoo
    {
        private readonly int ValueZero = 0;

        private readonly int ValueOne = 1;

        public int GetValue()
        {
            return ValueOne + ValueZero;
        }

        public Task<int> GetValues()
        {
            return Task.FromResult(GetValue());
        }
    }
}
```

I expected `Footype_Cymbolsar` to trigger an error when running `dotnet format EditorConfig --fix-style info --check`; it does not.

Comment: Maybe you need to put `dotnet_naming_symbols` and `dotnet_naming_style` lines before the `dotnet_naming_rule` lines so symbol `type_symbols` and style `pascal_case` is properly defined before accessing them in the `dotnet_naming_rule` lines.